# Flask @route decorator with variables

Tags: flask, routes

Why the fragment of code below  produces error in the line commented with “this produces error”? What should I do to correct it?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET']) 
@app.route('/lti/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
@app.route('/<fase>', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #this produces error!
@lti(request='initial', error=error, app=app) 
def index(lti=lti): 
    """ initial access page to the lti provider.  This page provides 
     authorization for the user. 

    :param lti: the `lti` object from `pylti` 
    :return: index page for lti provider 
    """ 
    return render_template('index.html', lti=lti)
```

Comment: What error is produced?

Answer (score 2):

`<fase>` is a variable placeholder.  It captures a string at that position in the url and passes that to the view function.  It is passed as a keyword with the same name as the placeholder, so the view function needs to accept an argument with the same name (or `**kwargs`).

```
@app.route('/<fase>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(fase=None, lti=lti):
    pass
```